# Front Garage Lights no power

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, light-fixture, garage

I'm a new to doing home improvement stuff and I've been doing okay electrical stuff for the house so far but today I ran into an issue out of my skillset while wiring up the front lights on the outside of the garage.

I installed one, flipped the breaker and saw it was working. Turned it off and installed the second one, but I had no power to either light. Took down the second light & noticed the black wires slipped out of the wire nut. I rewired connection on both but still no power.

Since then these are the things I have tried:

- Reset the all the GFCIs in the house

  - one in Garage
  - one in kitchen
  - both bathrooms
- Reset the breaker at the box for the garage.

I honestly don't know what I am missing. I feel like it's a GFCI type deal, but there's only one outside and its in the garage. I heard the Fridge outside reset with it when I checked it.

Is there something I am missing on why I am not getting power outside anymore?

Comment: Are there any splices upstream of the switch and lights? Have you checked at the switch for a failed splice?

Comment: Recheck all of your connections. If a wire slipped out of a wirenut, you’re not installing it correctly. Also make sure you’re using the right size nut for your wire size/count.

Comment: Yes, also if you are taping wire nuts to make them fall apart less, stop doing that altogether. Let them fall apart, in fact, give them a pull test and then let their failures teach you how to do them better.

Comment: Are those wire nuts inside junction boxes and the cable secured with knockout clamps?

Comment: How did you connect the 2nd light fixture? Was it a separate run from the breaker, or did you tap into the circuit for the first light and run out to the second? If you tapped off of the 1st fixture to run to the 2nd one, did you accidentally connect them in SERIES instead of in PARALLEL? If you did run the 2nd light circuit in parallel (as you should have), then most likely you have a bad connection where you made the tap connection in the 1st fixture.

Comment: JRaef -- The second fixture was tapped into the circuit for the first light. As in, the first light I connected only had 1 black/white/grnd wire but the second light had 2 back/white/ground cables.    Eel -- from what I can tell there are no splices upstream of the lights. How would I be able to tell that?  Z4 those wire nuts were inside of the junction box. I didn't see anything that looked like knockout clamps (I googled to see what they looked like)